Message loss with lock-free MPMC queue when threads exit
Issue
I am getting inconsistent behavior with message loss while attempting to use a MPMC lock-less queue (concurrentqueue) in the implementation of a mutual exclusion algorithm. In particular, I have noticed the following:

No message loss occurs before the termination procedure begins
If the critical section code is minimal (short millisecond sleep), then the termination procedure will result in lost messages , and so threads will hang waiting on sockets.
If the critical section code includes some work (perhaps sending a few TCP requests to an unrelated socket), then the termination procedure will succeed and all nodes will shutdown gracefully.

Relevant Code/Setup
I've had trouble coming up with a minimal example, but the basic architecture is such:

N nodes on N different servers
Each node contains:

application thread (executes critical sections)
N-1 reader threads (receives messages from other nodes)
coordinator thread (implements mutual exclusion protocol)
writer thread (sends messages to other nodes)



As far as message passing, we have:

reader threads -> MPMC -> coordinator (messages from other nodes)
coordinator -> MPMC -> writer (messages to send to other nodes)
application -> MPMC -> coordinator (request/leave critical section)

Here are what I believe to be the relevant parts of the code:
Application
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    client.cs_enter()  // Blocks until ready
    // do_some_work()
    sleep(5)
    client.cs_leave()
}

// wait for threads

Message
enum MessageKind { REQUEST, REPLY, CS_ENTER, CS_LEAVE, DONE, TERMINATE };
struct Message {
    MessageKind kind;
    uint32_t node;
    uint32_t timestamp;
};

Writer
while (true) {
    std::pair<uint32_t, Message> tm({ 0, Message::cs_enter() });
    q->wait_dequeue(tm);

    // MAX node means no more messages to send
    if (tm.first == std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()) break;

    // map contains node_id -> socket_fd mapping
    send_message((*map)[tm.first], tm.second);
}
// exit thread

Readers
while (true) {
    Message m = recv_message(fd);
    MessageKind k = m.kind;
    q->enqueue(m);
    if (k == TERMINATE) break;
}
// exit thread

Coordinator
while(true) {
    if (this->done && this->terminated.size() == this->config->nodes.size() - 1)
        break;

    Message m = Message::cs_enter();
    this->input_queue->wait_dequeue(m);
    switch (m.kind) {
        // handle message based on kind
    }
}
// inform writer no more work to do
this->output_queue->enqueue({ std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max(), Message::done() });
// exit thread

I'm at a complete loss on how to proceed. Arbitrarily increasing critical section execution time is a flimsy solution, and I have no idea how well it will hold up in all the environments this implementation will be tested in. I also have no idea why increasing the critical section execution time works in the first place, seeing as how it is unrelated to the protocol code.
Do the semantics of my code not guarantee message delivery? More precisely, does the following code guarantee the consumer will receive the message?
// Producer - thread 1
q->enqueue(message);
thread_exit()

// Consumer - thread 2
Message m;
q->wait_dequeue(m);

Or do I need to write more to guarantee this property? (Memory fences, etc.)

Have you tried replacing the lock-free queue with a plain old queue+lock? Lock-free containers may have very counterintuitive idea of "before" and "after", depending on the implementation. For example the item inserted by enqueue may not become available immediately after return from enqueue.

That's a good idea. At least then I can make sure it isn't a bug in my code that is causing the odd behavior.

@IgorG: Terms like "immediately" imply time rather than ordering, which is usually a red herring.  But yes, with multiple writers at once, even if an enqueue happens-before a read attempt, the read might still see the queue empty even if no other reader has claimed it.  e.g. because a previous write (by another thread) is still half-finished, and it claimed a bucket ahead of the one our completed write used.  Lock-free Progress Guarantees in a circular buffer queue discusses such a queue (which is not lock-free when it's full, empty, or both(!))
